# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method getDirectoryRead()

Tags: magento2, php, dependency-injection, admin-controller

I have a controller that works and does what i need it to do if i manually add a path like: **`$mediaImages = '/magento/pub/media/images/';`**

But i cant get the DirectoryList injection to work, it returns undefined method?

```
<?php
  namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\UpdateTable;

  class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_postFactory;
    protected $_filesystem;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \NewcastleMotorcycles\AdminMenu\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $filesystem
    )
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
  {
    $mediaImages = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('images/');

  }
}
```

The error i get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::getDirectoryRead()

I'm obviously missing somtehing, any advise would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using direct object manager, use It like

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

protected $_filesystem;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $_filesystem,
)
{
    $this->_filesystem = $_filesystem;
}
```

Now you can media path by,

```
$mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('images/');
```

Comment: I have tried with 'use' and get this error:

Fatal error: Trait '[VENDOR]\[MODULE]\Controller\Adminhtml\UpdateTable\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\[VENDOR]\[MODULE]\Controller\Adminhtml\UpdateTable\Index.php on line 6

Comment: can you share your code please ?

Comment: the error should avoid using `use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;` which described by Prashant.

Comment: I have added the 'use' correctly now and have it working, almost. I get Almost, i get Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/media/images/thumb_slider2f.jpg

Is their something i need to set with Magento? Like i say folder permissions are fine if i manually enter the path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\UpdateTable;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_postFactory;
    protected $_filesystem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \NewcastleMotorcycles\AdminMenu\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $mediaImages = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('images');

    }
}
```

After run command: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Almost, i get Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/media/images/thumb_slider2f.jpg

Is their something i need to set with Magento? Like i say folder permissions are fine if i manually enter the path?

Comment: Please give permission to your folder

Comment: That's what i mean. The permissions are fine. This controller can write and read from that folder if i manually add the path like this: $mediaImages = '/magento/pub/media/images/';

Comment: can you please share your output => echo $mediaImages = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('images');
die;

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/media/images/

Comment: This should be returning' magento/pub/media', right?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $filesystem
```

to this:

```
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem
```

It will solve the problem.